# python date not recognize with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, date, xlsxwriter

I wonder how to do to write a date in a cell and make excel recognize it as a date.
With the following Python code, using xlsxwriter module, I write dates in cells

```
    formatDate = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})
    if re.match('\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}', data):
        #print 'date:',data
        worksheet.write(row,col,data,formatDate)
    else:
        worksheet.write(row,col,data)
```

But when I open Excel all the values are at the left of the cell. If I edit the value and press enter without any modification then its recognized as a date and Excel write it on the right of the cell.

No calculation can be made while dates are not recognized.

Can anyone help me on this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Not being an Excel expert, this sounds more like an issue with Excel's automatic date recognition. Maybe working with [date formats in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8E10019E-D5D8-47A1-BA95-DB95123D273E#__toc320186183) will help.

Comment: Different approaches are explained in the [Working with Dates and Time](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html) section of the XlsxWriter docs. But in short dates are numbers in Excel not strings. And it is easier to use Python datetime to handle this.

Comment: Ok converting string to integer it works. Thanks